# How to redirect a website to a holding page with a link back to the original website

Tags: redirects

I am trying to work out how to redirect an existing website to a new intermediate page which then links back to the customers existing website. I can change DNS records to point to the new hosting server but problem is how to redirect from there back to their existing website.

Their existing website only works when it is called using the domain name, do an nslookup on the domain name and try and use the ip number to access it fails with 'You don't have permission to access / on this server.' I guess it is probably hosted on some sort of VPS which operates using the URL in the header.

Any suggestions how I can do this redirection.

Comment: you can do this by .htaccess rules.

Comment: I can have control of the new site and server but no control over the hosting of the currently existing site which we need to link to.

Comment: then I think you can not do.it require cpanel access.

Comment: If the site is hosted at both www.example.com and example.com (no www), you could change the DNS for only one of those hostnames (really "www" and ".", or the root host) to point to the new server and leave the other pointing to the old. The reason the site doesn't listen on the IP address is because the web server uses name-based virtual hosting. This allows any number of domains to share the same IP.

Comment: That would work for those that use www. but those that happen to use domain.com directly would bypass the holding page.